Static Select have a random initial value on iOS Slack App slack bolt python
I'm new to Slack app development. I am currently using Slack Bolt sdk for python.I have created a simple static select with 5 options :
class SectionStaticSelect(SectionBlock):
    def __init__(self):

        options_list : List[Option] = []
        for i in range(5):
            options_list.append(
                Option( 
                        value=f"select_option_{i}",
                        text= f"option{i}"
                    )
            )

        super().__init__(
            text=TextObject(
                type="mrkdwn",
                text="section"
            accessory=StaticSelectElement(
                action_id="select_option",
                options=options_list,
                placeholder="choose an option"
            ),
        )

This static select trigger my HomePage().push() function that simply trigger a new home page to the user client.
Here is the class HomePage  :
class HomePage:
    def __init__(self, *, client: WebClient, user_id: str):
        self.client = client
        self.user_id = user_id

    def push(self, view: View) -> SlackResponse:
        return self.client.views_publish(user_id=self.user_id, view=MainScreen())

class MainScreen(View):
    def __init__(
        self,
    ):
        blocks = [
           SectionStaticSelect()
        ]

        super().__init__(type="home", callback_id="home_view", blocks=blocks)

On desktop the app have the perfect expected behavior but on iOS, even if i haven't inputed any initial_option , the StaticSelect Slack Bolt element seems to take a random initial_value.

I tried to print the value return by the HomePage().push() and the printed value is the expected behavior and do not represent what is displayed on iOS

I expect the StaticSelect element to not have any initial_option as on desktop


